# readChar from stdin

Tags: r, io

I would like to read in one character at a time and convert it to a string command to execute once a space is entered. 
I tried

```
con <- file("stdin")
open(con, blocking=TRUE)
while(q!=" "){
  #q=scan("",what="", nmax=1)
  q=readChar(con,1)
  cmd[i]=q;i=i+1
}
eval(cmd)
```

but I seem to not understand `readChar()` correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question, but with a few flaws:

- you use `q`, `cmd` and `i` and never assign them which leads to immediate error and program abort on undefined symbols being used in tests or assignments
- you test for `q` at the top of your `while` loop but never give it a value (related to previous point)
- you assign in the vector with `i` but never set to `1` first
- you misunderstand how string concatenation works
- you misunderstand how input from the console works, it is fundamentally by *line* and not by character so your approach has a deadly design issue (and `blocking` makes no difference)
- you terminate the wrong way; your *sentinel* value of '' still gets assigned.
- you open a console and never close it (though that may be ok with `stdin`)
- you grow the result var the wrong way, but that doesn't matter here compared to all the other issues

If we repair the code a little, and use better style with whitespaces, no semicolons and an `<-` for assignment (all personal / common preferences) we get

```
con <- file("stdin")
open(con, blocking=TRUE)
cmd <- q <- ""
i <- 1
while (q != " ") {
    q <- readChar(con,1)
    cmd[i] <- q
    i <- i+1
}
print(cmd)  # for exposition only
close(con)
```

and note the final `print` rather than `eval`, we get this (and I typed the `ls` command letters followed by whitespace)

```
$ Rscript /tmp/marcusloecher.R
ls 
[1] "l" "s" " "
$
```

I suggest you look into `readLines()` instead.

And now that I checked, I see that apparently you also *never* accept an answer to questions you asked. That is an ... interesting outcome for someone from our field which sometimes defines itself as being all about incentives...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which I truly appreciate. To my defense, (i) my working(!) code was/is similar to yours, I just did not want to clutter my question with the obvious initialization steps (for brevity sake; I figured anyone in this forum would be able to run it if needed), (ii) me not accepting answers is an oversight that was not intentional, will change that in the future. (That said, I have had a total of 7 questions; 5 were sort of answered, so the "never" is a bit strong). My real question here indeed was your 5th bullet: can I not somehow read in char by char, only lines?

Comment: I did not take you to task for "unanswered" questions -- you have limited control over that. I took you to task for "unaccepted" questions -- and you are guilty of that for seven of seven.  That is just bad practice.  So look around the site and see the green 'tick marks' -- "accepted questions".  (Equally: "green" score boxen in the list format.)  That is a signal *you* are expected to give to the readers of a question thread you start.  See eg [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I am quite puzzled now: do you mean "accept an answer" (instead of a question)? I could have done that only 5 times so far and have accepted 2 answers in retrospect, thx for bringing my attention to this. Now I will hopefully be able to accept an answer to my question on whether it would be possible to truly read char by char like I could easily do in C.

Comment: Yes, sorry, yesterday's comment should have said '"unaccepted" answer' just like the original post.  Not every question gets good answers, but *never* accepting answers on multiple is either incredibly rude, or, as in this, a misunderstanding of how the site works.  Good we have that cleared up.  User-interfaces from R are a little trickly. Folks have used tcl/tk to interactive apps stop on click, or enter.  AFAIK there is also something on CRAN to deal with password entry, maybe it provides help. Frohes Fest, and cheers from Chicago.